# Ignore UrlHelper AmbientValues

Tags: asp.net-core

The UrlHelper that is somehow automatically injected into the ControllerBase and Views uses a RouteValueDictionary called AmbientValues (values from the last request) which is used for any values not overridden by being specified. The only way to avoid this from what I've read is to manually clear (myId = "") the values that you don't want.

This is extremely annoying and I really can't see why you would want this. In a small project it may be fine because you save a few minutes not having to specify all the parameters but in a big project you lose hours looking for redirects and links that are not clearing parameters that you didn't expect to be there when the redirects/links were written.

I just want the values that I explicitly specify to be included in my URL's and nothing else.

Is there a way to disable the use of AmbientValues in the UrlHelper or is there a way to replace the UrlHelper service with a custom one that doesn't do this? If so, how?